# SQL : Retrieve inserted row IDs array / table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i have the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, FIELD2)
SELECT f1, f2 FROM table2 -- returns 20 rows
```

after insert i need to know the array/table of IDs generated in table1.ID which is INT IDENTITY

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clause (SQL2005 and up):

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE(ID int)

INSERT INTO table1(Field1, Field2)
OUTPUT inserted.ID into @IDs(ID)
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM table2
```

If you want to know exactly which rows from table2 generated which ID in table1 (and Field1 and Field2 aren't enough to identify that), you'll need to use [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE(Table1ID int, Table2ID int)

MERGE table1 AS T
USING table2 AS S
ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Field1, Field2) VALUES(S.Field1, S.Field2)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, S.ID INTO @IDs(Table1ID, Table2ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the last ID, but i need All the IDs ( for the current example i must have 20 new IDs ) !